# Loading base64 string image to DocuVieware

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, itext, memorystream

Image files are saved in base64 string format in the database.
I'm trying to load the image using DocuVieware via MemoryStream but failed.

Does anyone tried this kind of approach?

```
        if (this.IsPostBack != true)
        {
            var file = new DataFileManager().GetImageByID(userID);
            byte[] byt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file.CurrentImage);
            DocuVieware1.LoadFromStream(new MemoryStream(byt, 0, byt.Length), true);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to replace:

```
byte[] byt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file.CurrentImage);
```

by:

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(file.CurrentImage);
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=netframework-4.8